# Difficulty figuring out how to calculate the angular frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I've been tasked with finding the angular frequency for a oscillating mass on a supposed friction-less surface. I've been told that the mass is pulled to the left and 0.25 seconds later reaches the point -4.5cm( I have chosen the equilibrium position to be x=0). At 0.725 seconds it reaches the position x = 4.5cm. I have no clue as how to solve this. I've tried writing simultaneous equations for the different points with their respective times and equated to cancel the amplitude but I still have not managed to figure out what the angular frequency is, please assist.

*I have also tried using the energy equations, but no luck.

Comment: Have a look at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/shm2.html and http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-calculate-the-angular-frequency-of-a-mass-o.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to do this in your head when you have the right picture.

[image]

Look at the symmetry of the situation. You should be able to figure out the time of the zero crossing, and thus the time of a quarter of an oscillation, just by eyeballing.

The frequency follows with simple math.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends whether the mass reaches the position from the left hand side or the right hand side ( according to your selection of origin or eq. position).
If both of the situations stand for reaching the position for the first time, i.e. x=-4.5 cm from the RHS and x=4.5cm from the LHS, then the mass has covered half of the total distance covered in a full oscillation ( you can easily see that from the geometrical interpretation of SHM which you must have studied). So, angular frequency= $pi/(0.725-0.25)$ radians per second

Comment: The time points 0.25 and 0.725 don't correspond to extrema of the motion, or to half an oscillation. See diagram in my answer.

Comment: I think you didn't read my full answer. 4.5 & -4.5 don't need to be the extreme points. The movement from 4.5 to -4.5 is half the oscillation considering it is reached for the first time in that particular oscillation.

Comment: It would be half an oscillation on the second time it reached the opposite amplitude. Again - see my diagram.